# extras.getString() retrieves right value but assigns null

Tags: java, android, startactivityforresult

I have this, let's say "homework" (don't how to translate it, sorry) to write mostly simple app for teachers so they can put grades and subjects etc.

I set up the activity that's using custom adapter and list view to display student names with 3 buttons at the and of each row for every student to set the grade. Buttons are 3 because students have 3 tries to pass. After you press the button the activity shows up (as popup) to put the grade from keyboard and save it as new text of that button that was pressed. I didn't manage yet how to set that button text to the grade that was passed from that activity, becasue I caonnot retrive that String in onActivityResult.
I made a pause on:

```
String s = extras.getString(key)
```

to check what value is found with that key I set up with putExtra() and after I get my app to that step I see:

```
s: null extras: Bundle[{key=4}]
```

right after that line of code I mentioned before, and 4 is the value I typed in EditText to pass back to first activity. Even though I see that the right value was passed from 2nd activity to 1st I cannot assign it to a new String I am creating in onActivityResult.

So in fewer words the proceess should be like this:
In 1st activity I click a button in a row of a list view created by custom adapter to open the activity for result. In 2nd activity I write a number in EditText and after button press I pass it as a result to onActivityResult back to 1st activity. I get the right number as extra but after assignment to a new String the string stays null.

1st I start activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Then I pass extra onClick from EditText like this:

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key", editText.getText());
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Then I go back to 1st activity to do this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            String s = extras.getString("key");  //1st Pasue
            Log.e("onactivityresult string", (String) s); //2nd Pause

        }
    }
}
```

1st pause:

```
Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=40]
```

Step over, 2nd pasue:

```
Bundle[{key=4}]
s = null
```

So back in 1st activity, in onActivityResult I think I can see that right value was passed from EditText in second activity but after assignment to new String it keeps setting it to null.
I don't know if I gave enough information but if would like more just ask and I will try to give you more.

EDIT:
This worked:

```
intent.putExtra("key", editText.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Because `editText.getText()` doesn't give string. You need to add `toString()` call too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EditText.getText()` returns an `Editable`, not a `String` directly. Use

```
intent.putExtra("key", editText.getText().toString());
```

when returning the result.